# Pull out data from a numbered variable using a loop in swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have a realm database. So that the database is more readable. I have designed the questionbank as follows:

```
class Question: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var answered: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var lastAnswer: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var howManyTimesAnswered: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var answer0: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var answer1: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var answer2: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var answer3: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var correctAnswer: Int = 0
    let parentCategory = LinkingObjects(fromType: Category.self, property: "questions") //back relationship to category
}
```

I am trying to pull out the answers and putting them into an array of tuples (String, Bool)

```
 var currentAnswers = [(String, Bool)]()
    for i in 0...3 {
        if i == question.correctAnswer {
            currentAnswers.append(("question.answer2", true))
        } else {
            currentAnswers.append((question.answer1, false))
        }
    }
```

what I want to achieve is something like this where the answer pulled out is equal to i obviously the one below will not compile

```
    for i in 0...3 {
        if i == question.correctAnswer {
            currentAnswers.append((question.answer(i), true))
        } else {
            currentAnswers.append((question.answer(i), false))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use [Key path](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/key_path_expressions)  Try this code

```
  var currentAnswers = [(String, Bool)]()
    for i in 0...3 {
        if i == question.correctAnswer {
            currentAnswers.append((question.value(forKey: "answer\(i)") as! String, true))
        } else {
            currentAnswers.append((question.value(forKey: "answer\(i)") as! String, false))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that it works like a charm. Just edited the casting

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get a workaround it. Only one line of extra code.
I hope this will help if someone wants to achieve something similar.

```
    var currentAnswers = [(String, Bool)]()
    let answers = [question.answer0, question.answer1, question.answer2, question.answer3]

    for i in 0...3 {
        if i == question.correctAnswer {
            currentAnswers.append((answers[i], true))
        } else {
            currentAnswers.append((answers[i], false))
        }
    }
```

I have been using tuple above for true randomization so that the answers always show up in different order on the answer buttons.